# How to fix button element in angular using CSS

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How to fix button element in angular using CSS
this error come from when I'm using mobile view

This is HTML Code

```
 <div class="button-containers">
            <button
              mat-stroked-button
              color="primary"
              [routerLink]="'/contracts/create/' + agency?.id">
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> New Contract
            </button>
          </div>
```

This is CSS Code

```
.info-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

.fee{
  min-width: 17em;
}

.button-container-reduced {
  padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;
}

.tab-reduced {
  padding: 0;
}

.btn-width-130{
  width: 130px;
}
.button-containers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

how can I fix this error using CSS

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq1bv.png]

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: can you see the message?

Comment: The button texts have different lengths, so the buttons have a different widths. With this styles it is expected behavior to me. It's not so clear to me what you are expecting.

Comment: @JSONDerulo shall I send the whole section with css

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class that use a fixed width for both buttons (contract & employees):

CSS

```
.btn-width-130{
   width: 130px;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="button-containers">
        <button
          class="btn-width-130"
          mat-stroked-button
          color="primary"
          [routerLink]="'/contracts/create/' + agency?.id">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> New Contract
        </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, but for internationalized applications, this is a no-go, because you cannot predict how long the texts will be in the different languages.

Comment: @JSONDerulo  i think it's the correct expected behavior, but if he want have same width for all buttons it's the only way

Comment: I think with flex it's also possible that the buttons will stretch automatically to the width of the widest button

Answer (score 0):

You can align the buttons with `justify-content: flex-start` left:

```
.button-containers {
  ...
  justify-content: flex-start;
  ...
}
```

or give the buttons a minimum width, for example:

```
.button-containers button {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```